# How to choose the type of t-test to use for analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, t-test

I did an A/B test on two different versions of an advert. I have the CTR of both variations of the ads for the last 10 days. I'd like to know what kind of `t-test` should I use to test the significance of change if there's any?

Comment: More information is required for a really useful response. Do you have response data for the two versions for the last 10 days? What are the responses? Counts of views or clicks? Opinions of viewers? Dollar sales of items advertised? (Ordinal categorical data or numerical data?) Do the same people respond to both versions on each day? (More technically, we'd need information whether data are paired.) Can you show the data? (So we can tell whether it reasonable to assume that the data are normal.)

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any sort of t-test you should really first check that the data is normally distributed. Depending on the distributions that you are comparing, a t-test might not be the right test to use at all.